# Jquery:Content search error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem about searching a text. I think it is Ja because of the whitespaces

This is my script that working.

```
$('td > a:contains("Hallow")').each(function(){
    if($(this).parent().next('td').text() == 'Secured') {
      alert("working well")
    }
    else {
      alert($(this).text());
    }
});
```

There is no whitespaces and my script is working : http://jsfiddle.net/FrE9Q/7/

```
<td width="140" align="right">Secured</td>
```

There is no whitespaces

---

Here is real html with whitespaces and my script isnt working: http://jsfiddle.net/FrE9Q/8/

```
        <td width="140" align="right">
        Secured
    </td>
```

Whitespaces...

Thank you for your helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then remove trailing and leading white spaces, using [`$.trim` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/):

```
if ($.trim($(this).parent().next('td').text()) === '...')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.trim()`

```
$('td > a:contains("Hallow")').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).parent().next('td').text();
    if ($.trim(text) == 'Secured') {
        alert("working well")
    }
    else {
        alert($(this).text());
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/FrE9Q/9/